# going crazy with Yahoo and sending emails from in mail client with MailKit

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient, yahoo, mailkit

I'm going crazy with Yahoo and sending emails from an mail client with MailKit which manage tons of email but I'm cannot send to Yahoo only.

I tried to follow not only the MailKit documentation (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SslHandshakeException) but also the several posts found by googling which definitely advise me not to use the MX record of yahoo but to use authentication for third party apps and using a fixed params as mailserver, port and TLS

Despite this, I cannot deliver emails to valid yahoo addresses, and the behavior is very bizarre: if I connect without authentication, yahoo tells me "554 Email rejected", but if I connect with yahoo authentication it tells me "550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable "when I receive tons of emails on the same email every day...I'm going to cry...

Here is the code and Yahoo's answer is there any good man to help me? Thank you so much in advance for your help, I have a very big problem with a customer.

Here the code used and the answers

**WITH AUTHENTICATION**

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, e) True
client.CheckCertificateRevocation = False
client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
client.Authenticate(username, password)
```

```
Connected to smtp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587/?starttls=always
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
EHLO mailsystem.xxxxx.xx
250-kubenode509.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello mailsystem.xxxxx.xx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 41697280
250 STARTTLS
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO mailsystem.xxxxx.xx
250-kubenode509.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello mailsystem.xxxxx.xx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]])
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 41697280
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
AUTH PLAIN ********
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
MAIL FROM:<no-reply@xxxxx.xx> SIZE=4892
RCPT TO:<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>
550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable
503 5.5.0 Need MAIL before RCPT
RSET
250 2.0.0 OK
```

**WITHOUT AUTHENTICATION**

```
client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, e) True
client.CheckCertificateRevocation = False
client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls)
```

```
Connected to smtp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587/?starttls=always
S: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
C: EHLO mailsystem.xxxxx.xx
S: 250-kubenode503.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello mailsystem.xxxxx.xx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]])
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-SIZE 41697280
S: 250 STARTTLS
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C: EHLO mailsystem.xxxxx.xx
S: 250-kubenode503.mail-prod1.omega.ir2.yahoo.com Hello mailsystem.xxxxx.xx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]])
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-SIZE 41697280
S: 250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
C: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@xxxxx.xx> SIZE=4892
C: RCPT TO:<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com>
S: 554 Email rejected
S: 503 5.5.0 Need MAIL before RCPT
C: RSET
S: 250 2.0.0 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of the `no-reply@address.com`. You need to use your yahoo mail address.

Comment: if I use "mta5.am0.yahoodns.net 25" TLS.none and no authentication, everything works well.....

Comment: If you use the MX records, the SMTP server you are directed to is not the same SMTP server that users connect to. The SMTP servers that users connect to require authentication and the sending address must match the account.

Comment: MX records are used by SMTP servers to relay messages to other SMTP servers.

Comment: What you SHOULD be doing to send mail is to connect to your own company’s SMTP server and letting it relay the messages to the appropriate yahoo SMTP server.

Comment: this is not possible in this situation, I have made dozens of solutions that rely on the SMTP Server of the customer's domain but in this case it is not possible, I must be the one who simulates an SMTP Server

Comment: Then use mta5.am0.yahoodns.net 25 without TLS/authentication.

Comment: at the end, I followed your suggestion.

But I need anothe info: I need to change in the message (smtpClient object) the "message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress(sendername, senderemail)" already prepared whit a new  ""message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress(sendername, yahooemail)".